# Flow Error - Apex CPU time limit exceeded in After Save Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, lightning-flow-builder

I am building an after save flow on Account. We have 2 checkbox fields on Account and 1 Number field :-

- Field 1 (checkbox)
- Field 2 (Checkbox)
- Acc Number (Text)

Logic - If we set Field 1 to TRUE for Account1 then find Accounts with same Acc Number of Account1 and set Field 2 to TRUE for all those Accounts.

Now Flow is working fine when we have around 130 accounts with same Acc Number. But for a specific Acc Number we have 170 Accounts and getting CPU Time limit error while processing those Accounts.

[image]

Comment: Can you successfully update the 170 accounts via data loader?  If yes, can you share a screenshot of your flow?  Is the flow doing any DML within a loop?  Flow is not as efficient as apex but it's pretty good so you may have other processes or code that is causing the issue.

Comment: Note that updating the related Accounts will initiate triggers and after save flows on those Accounts too.

Comment: @gorav Yes I am able tp update those 170 records directly from Execute Anonymous window in dev console. I attached the screen shot of my flow where I am adding all records in a collection variable only and then doing the update at then very end outside the loop.